# Finding the value of the infinite sum $1 -\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{7} - \frac{1}{10} + \frac{1}{13} - \frac{1}{16} + \frac{1}{19} + ... $

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, limits, closed-form

Can anyone help me to find what is the value of $1 -\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{7} - \frac{1}{10} + \frac{1}{13} - \frac{1}{16} + \frac{1}{19} + ... $ when it tends to infinity

The first i wanna find the pattern but it seems do not have any unique pattern can anyone help me?

Comment: @Olivier Oloa i dont understand how do you get the last 2 equation from your solution the problem i have now is the same with the other solution so can you help me?

Comment: @Deddy OK, I will edit my answer so as to provide some details.

Comment: @Arashium do you have any solution without integral?

Comment: Are you OK with my answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 20):

**Hint.** Observe that the general term of your series is 
$$\frac{(-1)^n}{3n+1}. $$
Then you may write
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{3n+1}&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\int_0^1 x^{3n} dx\\\\
&=\int_0^1 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nx^{3n} dx\\\\
&=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x^3} dx\\\\
&=\int_0^1 \left(\frac{1}{3 (1+x)}+\frac{2-x}{3 \left(1-x+x^2\right)}\right) dx\\\\
&=\frac{1}{3}\ln 2+\frac{\pi\sqrt{3}}{9}
\end{align}
$$

---

**Some details.**
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x^3} dx&=\frac{1}{3}\int_0^1\!\frac{dx}{(1+x)}+\frac{1}{3}\int_0^1\!\frac{2-x}{(x-1/2)^2+3/4} dx\\\\
&=\frac{1}{3}\ln 2+\frac{1}{3}\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}\!\frac{3/2-u}{u^2+3/4} du \quad (u=x-1/2, \,dx=du)\\\\
&=\frac{1}{3}\ln 2+\frac{1}{3}\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}\!\frac{3/2}{u^2+3/4} du\\\\
&=\frac{1}{3}\ln 2+\int_{0}^{1/2}\!\frac{1}{u^2+3/4} du\\\\
&=\frac{1}{3}\ln 2+\left.\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\arctan \left( \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}u\right)\right|_{0}^{1/2} \\\\
&=\frac{1}{3}\ln 2+\frac{\pi\sqrt{3}}{9}
\end{align}
$$ where we have used $\displaystyle \arctan \!\left(\! \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\!\right)\!=\frac{\pi}{6}$.

Comment: You are using the Dominated Convergence Theorem at the second row. Great solution Olivier

Comment: Thanks @PaoloLeonetti Another way is to just "control" the remainder here: $$ \int_0^1 \frac{x^{3N}}{1+x^3} dx\leq \int_0^1 x^{3N} dx=\frac{1}{3N+1} \to 0$$ as $N \to +\infty$.

Comment: @OlivierOloa do you have any solution without integral? Such using telescoping only maybe

Comment: @Deddy If you know the digamma function (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DigammaFunction.html), you can use it here, but this would be using integral in disguise... I think that if another solution is given, it will use integral, at least in disguise. Observe that these integrals are elementary ones. Telescoping sums can't hold here since the series sum is not rational. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

the series equal to 
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{6n+1}-\frac{1}{6n+4}$$
the first term
$$\frac{1}{1-x^6}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{6n}$$
$$\int_0^1\frac{1}{1-x^6}dx=\int_0^1\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{6n}dx$$
$$\int_0^1\frac{1}{1-x^6}dx=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{6n+1}$$

the second term

$$\frac{1}{1-x^6}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{6n}$$
 mutiply by $x^3$

$$\frac{x^3}{1-x^6}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{6n+3}$$
$$\int_0^1\frac{x^3}{1-x^6}dx=\int_0^1\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{6n+3}dx$$
$$\int_0^1\frac{x^3}{1-x^6}dx=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{6n+4}$$

hence 
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{6n+1}-\frac{1}{6n+4}=\int_0^1\frac{1}{1-x^6}dx-\int_0^1\frac{x^3}{1-x^6}dx=\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x^3}dx$$
$$=\frac{1}{3}\log 2+\frac{\pi\sqrt{3}}{9}$$

Comment: Is there any solution without integral?

Comment: can i have the proof of this one? $\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x^3}dx = =\frac{1}{3}\log 2+\frac{\pi\sqrt{3}}{9}$

Comment: The trouble with this solution is, the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{6n+1}$ and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{6n+4}$ are divergent. So you are evaluating $\infty-\infty$, like a physicist or something.

Comment: @TonyK: isn't math interesting enough? Do we really need rudeness wherever we go?

Comment: But @Gottfried, it's what physicists _do_. They call it renormalisation.

Comment: @TonyK: so it seems, that -at least- someone needs it. It is as it had to be expected. MSE- welcome sci.math...

Answer (score 2):

Look at the final answer. The final answer tells you this series cannot be calculated simply. Here I propose a solution although it is not a good solution:

$$\Sigma_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{(n+a)(n+b)}=\frac{H_a-H_b}{a-b}$$

Where $H_x$ is *harmonic number* of $x$.

(It can be replaced with digamma function too. Although $\psi_0(x)\neq H_x$, the result is remained the same.)

Computing $H_x$ is not easy too. It is as hard as calculation of integrals. But if you have its table, you can calculate the series.

In this case, if you know $H_{\frac16}$ and $H_{\frac23}$ you can solve this series (Odd condition!).

$$\Sigma_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(3n+1)}=\Sigma_{n=0}^\infty (\frac1{(6n+1)}-\frac1{(6n+4)})=\Sigma_{n=0}^\infty \frac3{(6n+1)(6n+4)}=1-\frac14+\frac3{36}\Sigma_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{(n+\frac16)(6n+\frac46)}=1-\frac14+\frac1{12}\times\frac{H_{\frac46}-H_{\frac16}}{\frac46-\frac16}=\frac34+\frac16(H_{\frac23}-H_{\frac16})$$

I need to know these two harmonic numbers (the big disadvantage of this method):

$$H_{\frac23}=\frac32+\frac\pi{2 \sqrt3}-\frac{3 \log 3}2$$

$$H_{\frac16}=6-\frac{\sqrt3 \pi}2-\frac{3 \log 3}2-\log4$$

$$H_{\frac23}-H_{\frac16}=-\frac92+\frac{2\pi \sqrt3}3+2\log 2$$

$$\Sigma_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(3n+1)}=\frac34+\frac16 (-\frac92+\frac{2\pi \sqrt3}3+2\log 2)$$

$$\therefore ~~~\Sigma_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(3n+1)}=\frac{\pi \sqrt3}9+\frac{\log2}3$$

Comment: can i know where can i find the list of the harmonic number?

Comment: For numbers higher than 1 there are some [propose numerical methods](http://fredrik-j.blogspot.com/2009/02/how-not-to-compute-harmonic-numbers.html) and there are some [numerical tables](http://www.seriesmathstudy.com/sms/ApproximateFormulaHarmonicNum) too. However, you need tables for simple fraction of small numbers and in symbolic way. Although they can be found in wolframalpha, a neat table of collection of them is something that I have not found on web. Maybe we need a pioneer to do that! :D